# How to delete Hibernate @Embeddables containing nullable fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When deleting an @Embeddable object, I run into some problems.

I have the following domain classes: SwitchVoipTrunkGroup and PrioritizedCodec. The latter contains several fields that are nullable.

```
class SwitchVoipTrunkGroup {

    //...

    @CollectionOfElements(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "SWITCH_VOIP_TKG_CODEC",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_SWITCH_VOIP_TKG_ID")
    )
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_CODEC_SWITCH_VOIP_TKG")
    private Set<PrioritizedCodec> prioritizedCodecs = new HashSet<PrioritizedCodec>();

    //...
}

@Embeddable
public class PrioritizedCodec {

    @Column(name = "PRIORITY")
    private String priority;

    @Column(name = "FAX_MODE")
    private String faxMode;

    //... some more columns ...
}
```

When I edit SwitchVoipTrunkGroup's prioritizedCodecs field (e.g. by deleting an entry) and save the entity, I see the following in my Hibernate logging:

```
13:54:31,919 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: delete from T_SWITCH_VOIP_TKG_CODEC where 
fk_switch_voip_tkg_id=? and fax_mode=? and priority=?
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742897/hibernate-elementcollection-strange-delete-insert-behavior) I understand why Hibernate uses all the fields in the where clause. However, this gives problems: in case some of these fields are empty, the query will look like so:

```
delete from T_SWITCH_VOIP_TKG_CODEC where fk_switch_voip_tkg_id=1 and fax_mode = '' 
and priority =''
```

This will however not delete any records, as what is really necessary is for Hibernate to check for NULL iso for an empty string. For example:

```
delete from T_SWITCH_VOIP_TKG_CODEC where fk_switch_voip_tkg_id=1 and fax_mode
IS NULL and priority IS NULL
```

(cf. [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/empty_null.php) for more info on why checking for an empty string does not suffice)

Any ideas on how to tackle this? Many thx!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't set the values of these attributes to null in your entity before doing the delete operation?

Comment: The fact that they are null is exactly the problem, because this makes Hibernate check for empty strings in the where clause.

Comment: Thing is, the concept of @Embeddable objects is that their lifecycle is tied to that of their parent - deleting them without deleting their parent seems off.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to normalize your database, so both your classes become entities, and then to setup  One-to-Many relation between SwitchVoipTrunkGroup  and  PrioritizedCodec, then you may setup cascading rules so Hibernate automatically updates collection of elements of PrioritizedCodec type, when you persist instance of SwitchVoipTrungGroup.

```
@Entity
class SwitchVoipTrunkGroup {

    //...

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "switchVoipTrunkGroup_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PrioritizedCodec_SwitchVoipTrunkGroup")
    private Set<PrioritizedCodec> prioritizedCodecs = new HashSet<PrioritizedCodec>();

    //...
}

@Entity
public class PrioritizedCodec {

        @Column(name = "PRIORITY")
        private String priority;

        @Column(name = "FAX_MODE")
        private String faxMode;

        //... some more columns ...
    }

@Serice("someService")
public class SomeService  {

     @Autowired 
     private SwitchVoipTrunkGroupDao trunkDao;

     public SwitchVoipTrunkGroup doOperation("criteria") {
         SwitchVoipTrunkGroup tg = trunkDao.find("criteroa");
         tg.getPrioritizedCodecs().[remove(2)]; //remove should be implemened, that is just lame statement
         tg.getPrioritizedCodecs().get(5).setFaxMod("ENABLED");
         return trunkDao.save(tg); //hibernate will remove missing elements from PrioritizedCodec table, and will update necessary entities.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may specify default values for priority and faxMode fields via attributes of @Column annotation and enforce nullable constraints

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20) default 'NONE'", nullable = false)
private String faxMode;
```