# JPA enumeration set not updated in database after remove from list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have User with roles in JPA (hibernate).
If I remove role from set on user it's not propagate to database.
So its still holded in the database.
(I also noticed that this happend only sometimes)
If I set the role set to null persist than set only the right role to the user set and persist again than its work.

```
public enum Role {
        USER("USER"),
        SPECIALUSER("SPECIALUSER"),
        ADMIN("ADMIN");

        private final String name;

        private Role(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
```

Declaration in User entity

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "USER_ROLES")
    @Column(name = "ROLE")
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

in transaction on managed entity

```
user.getRoles().remove(Role.ADMIN);
user.getRoles().remove(Role.SPECIALUSER);
```

I also try to flush but its not helped. I am quite confused...

Comment: This answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742897/hibernate-elementcollection-strange-delete-insert-behavior

Comment: @eyp Will try it but I think I also tried it once before.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an [@OrderColumn](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-optimize-hibernate-elementcollection-statements/) as well:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@CollectionTable(name = "USER_ROLES")
@Column(name = "ROLE")
@OrderColumn(name = "index_id")
private Set<Role> roles;
```