# Hibernate composite-key or surrogate-key

Tags: hibernate, composite-key, surrogate-key

I have to design a table for storing some remote data. The data I am getting, via web service, has a candidate key, combination of two columns, but I have seen few posts where they discourage using composite-key in hibernate instead recommending to use surrogate-key. If I design a table using composite-key then I can update the data directly but if I use surrogate-key then I have to fetch the primary-key first before updating. My question is which one should I use, composite-key or surrogate-key?

Answer (score 1):

Say no to Composite Key becasue...

- They are inefficient (depends on the database)
- cumbersome to use
- More number of parameters instead of just one
- prone to bugs
- May lead to duplciation of data if we have more than one column as composite key

Hence surrogate key is suggested. Though it has its own drawbacks

- Performance problems
- Error prone
- Duplication

As stated in **Java Persistence with Hibernate** reference:

> More experienced Hibernate users use saveOrUpdate() exclusively; it’s
>   much easier to let Hibernate decide what is new and what is old,
>   especially in a more complex network of objects with mixed state. The
>   only (not really serious) disadvantage of exclusive saveOrUpdate() is
>   that it sometimes can’t guess whether an instance is old or new
>   without firing a SELECT at the database—for example, when a class is
>   mapped with a natural composite key and no version or timestamp
>   property.

Some manifestations of the limitation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742897/hibernate-elementcollection-strange-delete-insert-behavior).

So use natural keys when it is relevant to do so and use surrogate keys when it is better to use them.

Comment: I have to update more than a million record, if I use surrogate-key then I have to do a select and update for all the record. Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: updating a million records sounds like you might want to do this without hibernate at all.