# Multiple save of a parent entity generate multiple entries for a ElementCollection in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

In my parent class I have this relation

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "PARENT_MYENUMS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"))
@Column(name = "MYENUM")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<MyEnum> myenums = new HashSet<>();
```

Where `MyEnum` is like that

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B
}
```

To add to my parents I use something like that

```
parent.getMyEnums().add(MyEnum.A);
```

But if I save the parent for multiple time when I have to do an update, the save multiply the data from collection table `PARENT_MYENUMS`

Any advice to prevent this multiple inserts in collection table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate - @ElementCollection - Strange delete/insert behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742897/hibernate-elementcollection-strange-delete-insert-behavior) - The behaviour you see is because hibernate cannot create a PK for the table `PARENT_MYENUMS` so each update on the collection results on a delete of the old associated values + an insert for each value in the Enum. I don't think there's a solution for a Set+@ElementCollection, so you might need to create an embeddable wrapper around the enum, but cannot say if that would work.

Comment: can you share where are you doing save or update.

Comment: also, use list if you absolutely doesn't need set

Comment: @saifulislamplabon I do an update I need a set because `MyEnum` have to be maximum just one of each type.

Comment: Ensure that in some other way, maybe prepersist ot pre update method or manually cleaning up duplicates. Because set doesn't play nice with jpa